# QTIFW readFile(string filePath, string codecName), what codec?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qt-installer

On QTIFW I see there is a function to read a file

```
string readFile(string filePath, string codecName)
```

but what codec means? How to use this function?

https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-installer.html#readFile-method

Comment: _using the encoding specified by codecName_ - so it's about encoding; I can only guess  - ANSII, utf-8, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Given the source code [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/installer-framework/installer-framework.git/tree/src/libs/installer/packagemanagercore.cpp?id=f747e559e12e4a9d675e26070d7d0c510d9106c8) (l.801), it seems related to file encoding. Since it is implemented using a `QTextCodec`, I'm assuming the valid values are the ones listed [there](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html#details).